# Project Euler 2

Tags: algorithm, scala

I am working on problem two of Euler.
I wanted to solve it this way, to compare the time after .

//Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the Fibonacci sequence which do not exceed four million

I should get 
//A: 4613732

but I am getting a huge number :

## 177112424089630957537

Can someone explain why ?

```
    def Fibonaccu(max: Int) : BigInt = {
            var a:BigInt = 0
            var b:BigInt = 1
            var sum:BigInt= 0
            var i:BigInt = 0;

            while(i < max){
                i+=1
                b = a + b 
                a = b - a   
                if (b % 2 == 0) sum += b 

            }

        //Return 
    println(sum)
    sum

    }

}
```

Comment: Your if condition is wrong! Question asks sum of even terms in Fibonacci sequence < 4 million, not first 4 million even numbers in Fibonacci sequence!

Comment: @NedStark : Correct me if I am wrong, I should evaluate every time the number generated by Fub function

Comment: And you don't need big int to calculate a number that is supposed to be `4613732`.

Comment: @NedStark Right! Can you please list the correct condition here .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here it is:

```
scala> val fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scanLeft(1)(_+_)
fib: Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> fib.takeWhile(4000000>).filter(_%2 == 0).sum
res0: Int = 4613732
```

And here is based on your code:

```
scala> def Fibonaccu(max: Int) : BigInt = {
     |             var a:BigInt = 0
     |             var b:BigInt = 1
     |             var sum:BigInt= 0
     |             while(b < max) {
     |                 if(b % 2 == 0) sum += b
     |                 b = a + b
     |                 a = b - a
     |             }
     |             sum
     | }
Fibonaccu: (max: Int)BigInt

scala> Fibonaccu(4000000)
res1: BigInt = 4613732
```

Comment: I'm not gonna be picky, but I really think adding "_" makes the code easier to read.
`fib.takeWhile(_<4000000).filter(_%2 == 0).sum`